# Android - Drawing on SurfaceView not appearing

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

> I simply want to draw a square over the camera preview on my android app. The camera preview displays on a SurfaceView, and from my reading online it seems that the best way to accomplish this was to place another SurfaceView over the one the camera feed displays on and draw on that. So I added this and also added some code but it isn't working, I see the camera feed no problem but the square never gets drawn. Just wondering if anybody had any thoughts on what I have missed. My DrawFocusRect function gets called, its just my rectangle never appears.

**My surface views in my layout xml file**

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/full_colour"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/TransparentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My drawing code, called from onPreviewFrame**

```
private static void DrawFocusRect()
{
    int hWidth = transparentView.getWidth();
    int hHeight = transparentView.getHeight();

    float f = (float) 0.5;
    float rLeft = (float) Math.floor(((1-f)/2)*hWidth);
    float rRight = (float) Math.floor((((1-f)/2)+f)*hWidth);
    float rTop = (float) Math.floor(((1-f)/2)*hHeight);
    float rBottom = (float) Math.floor((((1-f)/2)+f)*hHeight);

    canvas = holderTranspaernt.lockCanvas();

    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN, Mode.CLEAR);
    //border's properties
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(rLeft, rTop, rRight, rBottom, paint);

    holderTranspaernt.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Comment: [Have a look on zOrder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907615/draw-rectangle-on-surfaceview#comment40645043_25958527)

Comment: If you're not clear on what @SweetWisherシ means, see e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean) .  Also, if you want the stuff you're drawing on the surface to be transparent, you may need to set the porter-duff xfer mode and use a color with non-opaque alpha.

Comment: @SweetWisherヅ Can you add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct. You were absolutely right, when I added the following line to onCreate, everything worked fine. Many Thanks!! transparentView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You need to set **[zOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907615/draw-rectangle-on-surfaceview#comment40645043_25958527)** in order to handle ordering of the view drawn on SurfaceView.

Try setting [setZOrderOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)) for your view :

```
transparentView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: I can't use this in my situation, because there is a view "Game Over View" that needs to go over the surfaceview if it is game over